# Showing similarity of triangles

Tags: geometry, transformation

Let be $abc$ and $a'b'c'$ two triangles with same angles, so $ \alpha= \alpha ', \beta= \beta', \gamma= \gamma ' $

I want to show that the triangles are similar to each other by describing a similarity transformation  (a translation and scaling) which maps $abc$ onto $a'b'c'$.

I am not sure how to describe that transformation .. my idea is first rotating triangle by a factor $ \mu$ $ abc$  $$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix} $$
How do I proceed with the scalling?
Do I understand it right: Two triangles are similar if you can express one triangle as a concatenation of a translation and scalling of the other?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Not only a translation: any isometry would do.

Comment: Start by translating $a'$ to $a$ and then rotating about $a$ so that $b'$ is on $\overrightarrow{ab}$. I'm not sure what the identity matrix is doing for $A$.